# Writing the characteristic equation of a quasilinear equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

Given the quasilinear equation $u_{x} + u_{y} = e^{-u}$ with the initial conditions

- $x(0, s) = s$
- $y(0, s) = -s$
- $u(0, s) = \ln(s^{2})$

how can I write the characteristic equation where

- $a(x, y, u) u_{x} + b(x, y, u) u_{y} = c(x, y, u)$
- $\frac{dx}{dt} = a(x, y, u)$
- $\frac{dy}{dt} = b(x, y, u)$
- $\frac{du}{dt} = c(x, y, u)$

I took a look at Yehuda Pinchover & Jacob Rubenstein's *An Introduction to Partial Differential Equations*; the book that my instructor was using, but it was of no help. I am unsure on what am I suppose to do with $x_{t} = a(x, y, u)$ and $x(0, s) = s$ since $x_{t}$ doesn't have an interval/values that I can solve for.

I'd appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case $a=1$ $b=1$ and $c(u)=e^{-u}$. Therefore, the characteristic system is
$$
dx/dt=1, \quad dy/dt=1,\quad du/dt=e^{-u},
$$
so the (projections of) the characteristics on the $XY$-plane are straight lines. Along those, $u$ evolves according to the last equation.

Comment: I see, I had the impression that I was to integrate $x_{t}$ and then do $x_{t} = x(0, s)$ somehow. Tha clear it up, thank you.